# HTML5 Video - Failed to load resource error after it starts playing

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, buffer

I'm working on a video heavy site, and an event triggers a few videos to start playing, but one of the larger ones unloads itself after a second or two, resulting an error:

> FAILED TO LOAD RESOURCE ERROR

even though it was loaded a moment ago.

Staggering the buffering of each video helps slightly, but the unloading still happens occasionally. Any suggestions on managing this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is perhaps too little information in the post to give an exact answer but I would look into bandwidth (computer and internet) and video bit-rates as a first point. What dimensions are the videos and at what bit-rate are they encoded at would be an important question (HD, PAL/NTSC, custom).

Bandwidth problems can happen at several stages:

1. Is the server capable of delivering the total bit-rate required (sum of the video bit-rates + overhead) which must be continuously at this bit-rate as a minimum. This is not just about the internet bandwidth the server has available but also factors such as loading from storage, server load and so forth.
2. Is the internet connection (the bottle neck point) able to pass through this bit rate. If total bit-rate of videos supersede the available bandwidth incl. overhead you won't be able to load the streams fast enough
3. Is the computer able to buffer and decode all these video streams simultaneously. If the videos are for example HD (even if they are scaled down in the browser window the initial frame will be decoded at full frame dimension) the computer would need to decode and compute a huge amount of data even if it is hardware accelerated.

It could be any point really but I would perhaps start with point 3 if you already know your internet connection is more than capable (including overhead). Also if the browser uses the disc as a temporary cache for the buffer the disc will become a factor as well (seek times, fragmentation).

To eliminate you should find out what the bit-rate is for each video, sum them and see if your internet connection can handle it, if it does, do a test against the server to see if it has problems delivering the content streams. If none shows any sign of problems try to run your application with videos from local disc (through a local server) and see if your computer is capable of decoding all simultaneously.

Even if unlikely there are also the possibilities of (packet) errors in transmission regardless of good bandwidth as well as the video stream's encoding themselves (general file errors, atypical encoding scheme in case these are video container files etc.).